# This extension doesn't work for me?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is inside my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "ROBLOX Forum Link Fixer",
  "description": "Fixes the amp; issue on the ROBLOX forum.",
  "version": "2.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "jquery.js",
      "fixer.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://*.roblox.com/*",
    "https://*.roblox.com/*"
  ]
}
```

and this is inside of fixer.js (jquery.js is just jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rbx-link.user-link').each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/amp;/g, ""));
        $(this).attr("href",$(this).text());
    });
});
```

and the error is it just doesn't work and I don't know why?! I hope someone can help! Thanks.

Comment: Content scripts, not background scripts.

Comment: @dsg so just change background to content? I'm not good at this google chrome extension stuff yet. This is my first one.

Comment: Please take time to read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to  use the content script permission like

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.co.in/*",
       "https://www.google.co.in/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and not background see h[ttps://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)